# Plotly 3D plot with right aspect ratio

Tags: python, plotly, aspect-ratio, bin-packing

the relevant post is here: [interactive 3D plot with right aspect ratio using plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318810/interactive-3d-plot-with-right-aspect-ratio-using-plotly)

For a further improvment, I am wondering how to plot a container frame according to the bin size, so the graph can display more clearly how much spare space is left, when container is not full? just like what is shown below:

[image]

**UPADTE: drawing outer container frame**

```
def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    # defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is
    # discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM,
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym,
         None, yM, yM, None, yM, yM]
    z = [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM,
         None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z

x, y, z = parallelipipedic_frame(0, 1202.4, 0, 235, 0, 269.7)
# fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode="lines", line_width=4))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        z=z,
        mode="lines",
        line_color="blue",
        line_width=2,
        hoverinfo="skip",
    )
)

ar = 4
xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
fig.update_layout(
    title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    # autosize=False,
    scene=dict(
        camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
        aspectratio={
            **{"x": ar},
            **{
                c: ((max(d[c].max()) - min(d[c].min())) / xr) * ar
                for c in list("yz")
            },
        },
        aspectmode="manual",
    ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: can you share full code last picture? Please i need this so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame consists of segments, and a segment is drawn between two points. Hence I cannot give the code for plottin the frame only from  your length, width and height.
I need the coordinates of the parallelipiped vertices, i.e. x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max(), etc (see above), denoted xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    #defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is 
    discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM, 
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym, 
         None, yM, yM,None, yM, yM]
    z= [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM, 
        None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z

x, y, z= parallelipipedic_frame(2.3, 4.5, 0,5, 0, 2)
fig=go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode="lines", line_width=4))
fig.update_layout(width=600, height=450, font_size=11,  scene_aspectmode="data", 
                  scene_camera_eye=dict (x=1.45, y=1.45, z=1), template="none")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "parallelipiped vertices".   how to integrate with my existing codes?my full codes is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318810/interactive-3d-plot-with-right-aspect-ratio-using-plotly

Comment: there is a function about x,y,z, coordinations, is this what you looking for?                                                                                                                     
     def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
 return {
  "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
  "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
  "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
  "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
  "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
  "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
 }

Comment: Yes, xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM are x.min(), x.max(), etc for the arrays, x, y, z that are passed to go.Mesh3d.

Comment: I still have some problems not being able to plot correctly. could you take a look at the full codes here and how to make adjustment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318810/interactive-3d-plot-with-right-aspect-ratio-using-plotly

Comment: It's just a problem of elementary geometry to plot such a frame. I don' t have matplotlib installed on my system.

Comment: i am able to draw the outer container frame (see my edit), but the plot is left shifted, how to position the graph in the center.  how to delete the upper right trace line?

Comment: I am using plotly, as you can refer to the full codes in anwer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71318810/interactive-3d-plot-with-right-aspect-ratio-using-plotly   I just add some code (in my update above) but the graph is left shifted. how to make the graph center and not showing the trace line.

Answer (score 1):

To get a realistic 3d plot, you should set in layout, `scene_aspectmode='data'`.

To plot the container frame, retrieve from data used to plot the voxels, `x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max(), z.min(), z.max()`, if x, y, z are arrays or min(x) etc if they are lists. Then add to your plotly figure a scatter3d plot, `mode="lines"` to draw the lines for container frame. I checked it for  a partial frame attached to my own  voxel plot, and it works:
[image: voxels]

Comment: thanks. besides the boxes inside, how to draw a container frame like above graph.

Comment: the 40HC container: length width and height are 1202.4, 235, 269.7.  could you please provide the code for ploting the boundary of the container?