# Plotly: how to avoid huge html file size

Tags: python, plotly

I have a 3D bin packing model which uses plotly to draw the output graph. I noticed that with 600+items being ploted, it takes a long time to generate the html file and the file size is 89M, which is crazy (I doubt there might be some huge duplications, or caused by “add_trace” method to individual item plot). why does it make such a big file? How to control the size to an acceptable level (no more than 5M as I need to render it in my website). many thanks for the help.

[image]

below is my full code (please skip the model code and see from the plotly code)

```
from py3dbp import Packer, Bin, Item, Painter
import time
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly
import pandas as pd

start = time.time()
import numpy as np

# -----------this part is about calculating the 3D bin packing problem to get x,y,z for each items of a bin/container--------------
###library reference: https://github.com/jerry800416/3D-bin-packing

# init packing function
packer = Packer()
#  init bin
# box = Bin('40HC-1', (1203, 235, 259), 18000.0,0,0)
box = Bin('40HC-1', (1202.4, 235, 269.7), 18000.0, 0, 0)
packer.addBin(box)


# add item
# for num in range(10):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}", 'cube', (120, 120, 120), 8.20, 1, 100, True, 'red'))
# for num in range(55):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}", 'cube', (65, 38, 90), 14, 1, 100, True, 'blue'))
# for num in range(50):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}", 'cube', (143, 52, 47), 10, 1, 100, True, 'gray'))


# add item
# for num in range(12):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}", 'cylinder', (120, 120, 120), 8.20, 1, 100, True, 'red'))
# for num in range(120):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}", 'cube', (65, 38, 90), 14, 1, 100, True, 'blue'))
# for num in range(60):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}", 'cube', (143, 52, 47), 10, 1, 100, True, 'gray'))


# for num in range(12):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}", 'cylinder', (120, 120, 120), 8.20, 1, 100, True, 'red'))
# for num in range(33):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}", 'cube', (65, 38, 90), 14, 1, 100, True, 'blue'))
# for num in range(32):
#   packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}", 'cube', (143, 52, 47), 10, 1, 100, True, 'gray'))


for num in range(252):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxA_{num}", f"BoxA_{num}", 'cube', (65, 33, 26), 2.06, 1, 100, True, 'red'))
for num in range(222):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxB_{num}", f"BoxB_{num}", 'cube', (84, 42.5, 33), 2.72, 1, 100, True, 'blue'))
for num in range(270):
    packer.addItem(Item(f"BoxC_{num}", f"BoxC_{num}", 'cube', (48, 48, 38), 2.17, 1, 100, True, 'gray'))



# calculate packing
packer.pack(bigger_first=True, distribute_items=False, fix_point=True, number_of_decimals=0)

# print result
b = packer.bins[0]
volume = b.width * b.height * b.depth
print(":::::::::::", b.string())

print("FITTED ITEMS:")
volume_t = 0
volume_f = 0
unfitted_name = ''
for item in b.items:
    print("partno : ", item.partno)
    print("color : ", item.color)
    print("position : ", item.position)
    print("type of : ", item.typeof)
    print("rotation type : ", item.rotation_type)
    print("W*H*D : ", str(item.width) + '*' + str(item.height) + '*' + str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ", float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ", float(item.weight))
    volume_t += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print("UNFITTED ITEMS:")
for item in b.unfitted_items:
    print("partno : ", item.partno)
    print("color : ", item.color)
    print("W*H*D : ", str(item.width) + '*' + str(item.height) + '*' + str(item.depth))
    print("volume : ", float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth))
    print("weight : ", float(item.weight))
    volume_f += float(item.width) * float(item.height) * float(item.depth)
    unfitted_name += '{},'.format(item.partno)
    print("***************************************************")
print("***************************************************")
print('space utilization : {}%'.format(round(volume_t / float(volume) * 100, 2)))
print('residual volumn : ', float(volume) - volume_t)
print('unpack item : ', unfitted_name)
print('unpack item volumn : ', volume_f)
print("gravity distribution : ", b.gravity)
stop = time.time()
print('used time : ', stop - start)


# draw results
# painter = Painter(b)
# painter.plotBoxAndItems()

# ----------------------------------end---------------------------------------------


############################### PLOTLY ############################################
# https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
def vertices(xmin=0, ymin=0, zmin=0, xmax=1, ymax=1, zmax=1):
    return {
        "x": [xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax],
        "y": [ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax, ymax, ymin],
        "z": [zmin, zmin, zmin, zmin, zmax, zmax, zmax, zmax],
        "i": [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 0, 3, 6],
        "j": [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
        "k": [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 2],
    }


def parallelipipedic_frame(xm, xM, ym, yM, zm, zM):
    # defines the coords of each segment followed by None, if the line is
    # discontinuous
    x = [xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xM, xM, xm, xm, None, xm, xm, None, xM, xM,
         None, xM, xM, None, xm, xm]
    y = [ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, yM, yM, ym, None, ym, ym, None, ym, ym,
         None, yM, yM, None, yM, yM]
    z = [zm, zm, zm, zm, zm, None, zM, zM, zM, zM, zM, None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM,
         None, zm, zM, None, zm, zM]
    return x, y, z


def slice_triangles(z, n, i, j, k, l):
    """Create the triangles of a single slice"""
    return [[z, j, i], [i, j, l], [l, j, k], [k, n, l]]


def cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40):
    """Create a cylindrical mesh"""
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_slices + 1)
    x = xs + r * np.cos(theta)
    y = ys + r * np.sin(theta)
    z1 = zs + 0 * np.ones_like(x)
    z2 = (zs + h) * np.ones_like(x)

    # index of the final point in the mesh
    n = n_slices * 2 + 1

    # build triangulation
    triangles = []
    for s in range(1, n_slices + 1):
        j = (s + 1) if (s <= n_slices - 1) else 1
        k = j + n_slices if (s <= n_slices - 1) else n_slices + 1
        l = s + n_slices
        triangles += slice_triangles(0, n, s, j, k, l)
    triangles = np.array(triangles)

    # coordinates of the vertices
    x_coords = np.hstack([xs, x[:-1], x[:-1], xs])
    y_coords = np.hstack([ys, y[:-1], y[:-1], ys])
    z_coords = np.hstack([zs, z1[:-1], z2[:-1], (zs + h)])
    vertices = np.stack([x_coords, y_coords, z_coords]).T

    return vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2

# def cylinder_traces(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices=40, show_mesh=True, n_sub=4, surface_kw={}, line_kw={}):
def cylinder_traces(r, xs, ys, zs, h, color, name, n_slices=40, show_mesh=True, n_sub=4, line_kw={}):
    """
    r : radius
    xs, ys, zs : start position of the cylinder
    h : height of the cylinder
    n_slices : number of slices in the circumferential direction
    show_mesh : whether to display pseudo-wireframe
    n_sub : number of subdivision in along the height for the pseudo-wireframe
    surface_kw : customize the appearance of the surface
    line_kw : customize the appearance of the wireframe
    """
    vertices, triangles, x, y, z1, z2 = cylinder_mesh(r, xs, ys, zs, h, n_slices)
    # surface = go.Mesh3d(
    #   x=vertices[:, 0], y=vertices[:, 1], z=vertices[:, 2],
    #   i=triangles[:, 0], j=triangles[:, 1], k=triangles[:, 2],
    #   **surface_kw)
    # print("box_id: ", name)
    surface = go.Mesh3d(
        x=vertices[:, 0], y=vertices[:, 1], z=vertices[:, 2],
        i=triangles[:, 0], j=triangles[:, 1], k=triangles[:, 2],
        color=color, name=name)

    traces = [surface]
    if not show_mesh:
        return traces

    line_kw.setdefault("showlegend", False)
    # horizontal mesh lines
    zsubs = np.linspace(zs, zs + h, n_sub + 1)
    for zc in zsubs:
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=zc * np.ones_like(x), mode="lines",name=name, **line_kw))
    # vertical mesh lines
    for _x, _y in zip(x, y):
        traces.append(go.Scatter3d(x=[_x, _x], y=[_y, _y], z=[zs, zs + h], mode="lines", name=name, **line_kw))
        # print("traces: ", traces)
    return traces


# take a packer item and build parameters to a plotly mesh3d cube
def packer_to_plotly(item):
    colors = ["crimson", "limegreen", "green", "red", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow"]
    ret = vertices(
        *item.position, *[sum(x) for x in zip(item.position, item.getDimension())]
    )
    ret["name"] = item.name
    ret["color"] = colors[ord(item.name.split("_")[0][-1]) - ord("A")]
    return ret


# create a figure for each bin
fig = go.Figure()

# add a trace for each packer item
for row, pbin in enumerate(packer.bins):
    for item in pbin.items:
        fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(packer_to_plotly(item)))

    # some first attempts at sorting out layout, prmarily aspect ratio
    fig.update_layout(
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(
                # eye=dict(x=0.1, y=0.1, z=1.5)
            ),
            aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=.2, z=0.2),
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )

# push data into a data frame to enable more types of analysis
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "bin_name": b.partno,
            "bin_index": i,
            **packer_to_plotly(item),
            "item_typeof": item.typeof,
            **{d: v for v, d in zip(item.getDimension(), list("hwl"))},
            **{d + d: v for v, d in zip(item.position, list("xyz"))},
        }
        for i, b in enumerate(packer.bins)
        for item in b.items
    ]
)
# print("dataframe: \n", df['item_typeof'])

# create a figure for each container (bin)
for pbin, d in df.groupby("bin_name"):
    fig = go.Figure()
    xx = []
    yy = []
    zz = []

    # create a trace for each box (bin)
    for _, r in d.iterrows():
        # print("_, ", _,)
        # print("r ", r)
        if r["item_typeof"] == 'cube':
            fig.add_trace(
                go.Mesh3d(r[["x", "y", "z", "i", "j", "k", "name", "color"]].to_dict())
            )
            xx += [r.xx, r.xx + r.h, r.xx + r.h, r.xx, r.xx, None] * 2 + [r.xx] * 5 + [None]
            yy += [r.yy, r.yy, r.yy + r.w, r.yy + r.w, r.yy, None] * 2 + [
                r.yy,
                r.yy + r.w,
                r.yy + r.w,
                r.yy,
                r.yy,
                None,
            ]
            zz += (
                    [r.zz] * 5
                    + [None]
                    + [r.zz + r.l] * 5
                    + [None]
                    + [r.zz, r.zz, r.zz + r.l, r.zz + r.l, r.zz, None]
            )

            fig.add_trace(
                go.Scatter3d(
                    x=xx,
                    y=yy,
                    z=zz,
                    mode="lines",
                    line_color="black",
                    line_width=2,
                    hoverinfo="skip",
                )
            )
        else:
            name = r["name"]
            color = r["color"]
            radius = float(r["w"])/2
            height = float(r["l"])
            x_list = r["x"]
            # print("x_list: ", x_list)
            y_list = r["y"]
            # print("y_list: ", y_list)
            z_list = r["z"]
            x_min = float(min(x_list))
            # print("x_min ", x_min)
            x_max = float(max(x_list))
            # print("x_max ", x_max)
            y_min = float(min(y_list))
            y_max = float(max(y_list))
            x_cor = x_min + (x_max - x_min)/2
            y_cor = y_min + (y_max - y_min)/2
            z_cor = float(min(z_list))
            # print("xyz! ", x_cor,y_cor,z_cor)
            # colorscale = [[0, '#636EFA'], [1, '#636EFA']]
            # print("colorscale ", colorscale)
            fig.add_traces(
            #   cylinder_traces(radius, x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, height, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3})
            # )
            cylinder_traces(radius, x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, height, color, name, n_sub=1,
                            line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3}))


    x, y, z = parallelipipedic_frame(0, 1202.4, 0, 235, 0, 269.7)

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            z=z,
            mode="lines",
            line_color="blue",
            line_width=2,
            hoverinfo="skip",
        )
    )

    # -----------------newly added code to test plotting cylinder
    # fig.add_traces(
    #   cylinder_traces(50, 0, 0, 0, 80, n_sub=1, line_kw={"line_color": "#202020", "line_width": 3})
    # )

    # -----------------end for newly added code to test plotting cylinder-------------------

    ar = 4
    xr = max(d["x"].max()) - min(d["x"].min())
    # fig.update_layout(
    #   showlegend=False,
    #   title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
    #   margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
    #   # autosize=False,
    #   scene=dict(
    #       camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
    #       aspectmode="data",
    #   ),
    # )
    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        title={"text": pbin, "y": 0.9, "x": 0.5, "xanchor": "center", "yanchor": "top"},
        margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "t": 0, "b": 0},
        # autosize=False,
        scene=dict(
            camera=dict(eye=dict(x=2, y=2, z=2)),
            aspectratio={
                **{"x": ar},
                **{
                    c: ((max(d[c].max()) - min(d[c].min())) / xr) * ar
                    for c in list("yz")
                },
            },
            aspectmode="manual",
        ),
    )



    plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='C:/Users/mike/Desktop/3D_BinPack_' + str(row) + '.html', auto_open=False,
                        config={'displaylogo': False})
    # fig.write_html('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/3D_BinPack_' + str(row) + '.html', auto_open=False,
    #              include_plotlyjs="cdn",config={'displaylogo': False})
    fig.show(config={'displaylogo': False})
```

Comment: The html file created by the `plotly` has all the data necessary for graph plotting, so naturally the file size will be large depending on its contents. Reducing file size is a trade-off for content.

Comment: I need a solution please

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Any insight/package/idea will be greatly apprecaited. I'm looking into actually contributing to plotlyjs to help reduce the size of the data in the html, if someone can even point out where in the code is that done then that would be amazing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use plotly's `.to_html()` function to create the html file. In the function there is an argument that determines whether the plotlyjs source code is included or not - by including the code, the .html file becomes usable without an internet connection, but makes the file size considerably larger. However, you can opt to exclude the plotlyjs source code with the argument `include_plotlyjs='cdn'`. This will make the file much smaller, but means the file can only be viewed online.

You should be able to save your figure (fig) to an .html file as follows:

```py
f = open('filename_here.html', "w")
f.close()
with open('filename_here.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
f.close()
```

Again, this will write your fig to a file that requires an internet connection to view, but will be quite small compared to a file that is include the js source code.

If you want to create a file that is available offline (with the tradeoff of a larger file size) you can change the `include_plotlyjs` parameter to `True` as in the following:

```py
f = open('filename_here.html', "w")
f.close()
with open('filename_here.html', 'a') as f:
    f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs=True))
f.close()
```

**Note**: I've included the first `open` and `.close()` calls to show how to make sure the file you are writing to is empty first. Doing this will clear the file, then add your figure. Without first clearing the file, if you run the program multiple times with the same output file, you could end up 'appending' to the file, making it larger and larger each time.

Please let me know if this works for you.

---

**As a bonus**: if you *do* want to write multiple figures to a single .html file, you can create a list or dictionary of plotly figures, then iterate through the list/dictionary with the file open, writing the new figure on each iteration before closing the file:

```py
dictionary_of_figures = {} ### add your figures to this dictionary
   
f = open(filename_here.html,"w")
f.close()
with open(filename_here.html, 'a') as f:
    for key in dictionary_of_figures:
        f.write(dictionary_of_figures[key].to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Please let me know whether you were able to get it to work as desired.

Comment: Great examples! Note that your `dictionary_of_figures` needs to be properly setup. For example, `dictionary_of_figures = {fig, fig}` does not work. Instead, you must add the keys and values explicitly as shown: `dictionary_of_figures = {'fig1': fig, 'fig2': fig}`. Now it will work!

Comment: Great answer. Probably not a significant reduction for OP though, as the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/) mention: "HTML files generated with include_plotlyjs='cdn' are about 3MB smaller than those generated with include_plotlyjs=True"

Comment: 89 MB in OPs case is bigger than a typical plot file (in my experience) so I'd presume the file reduction will also be greater than 3 MB... that said, I'll let OP comment on whether it was sufficient for his needs.